# Are deleted WhatsApp messages still recoverable even after deleting a contact

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I deleted a particular WhatsApp conversation. Then I deleted the same contact. Now I uploaded the contact again but I am unable to see my deleted messages. I don't see the option of restoring messages after reinstalling WhatsApp. Why is this so? And is there a way out?

Comment: "I don't see the option of restoring messages" is this a rooted device?

Comment: What does rooted device mean

Comment: No it's nt a rooted device....

Comment: Why do I not see the option of restoring my messages on reinstalling whats app

Answer (score 4):

If you have automatic backups sent to Google Drive, that will be your easiest solution. If not, search for a local backup on your phone itself and recover with this method:

> Your phone will store up to the last 7 days worth of local backup files (Google Drive will only have the most recent). If you wish to restore a local backup which is not the most recent, you will need to do the following:
>
> 1. Download a file manager.
> 2. In the File Manager, navigate to sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases. If your data is not stored on the SD card, you may see internal storage or main storage instead of sdcard.
> 3. Rename the backup file you wish to restore from `msgstore-YYYY-MM-DD.1.db.crypt12` to `msgstore.db.crypt12`. It is possible that your earlier backup may have been on an earlier protocol, such as crypt9 or crypt10. Do not change the number of the crypt extension.
> 4. Uninstall WhatsApp.
> 5. Install WhatsApp.
> 6. Tap Restore when asked.

https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20887921